# Facebook application Review failed - "Your app downloads successfully, but crashes upon opening"

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-login

I submitted my iPhone application for Facebook login Review submission. Facebook responded by saying

**iPhone**
Your app downloads successfully, but crashes upon opening. Please resolve any technical issues that prevent us from testing your app.

I sent them simulator build after testing.

I used [simlaunch](https://github.com/landonf/simlaunch/) to test simulator build by my side.

I can see the app runs on my iPad simulator. What could be the reasons that crashed the reviewer's simulator?

Comment: Is there any logs that they have sent when app crashed??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook using ios-sim to test your applocation.
Try with ios-sim. If your app works with ios-sim then you are able to submit simulator build for review your app.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS Simulator is a tool for testing applications. **It is NOT a substitute for testing your application on real hardware.** Your application has been rejected because it crashes when run on an actual iPad — you need to reproduce this issue (again: on real hardware, not the simulator) and correct it.

Comment: My app also running fine on iPad/iPhone device.

Comment: My issue is, I am using Facebook SDK for wall post. But facebook want simulator build/iTunes ID for testing to approve my facebook app. Its my first upload. So, I can't give itunes ID for testing. Thats why I sent simulator build. Build working for me but not working for facebook review team